# Getting value from Sky form Date picker with PHP

Tags: php, html, date

I have a skyform date picker and I cannot seem to extract the values of selected dates. Everything else works. The HTML is:

```
 <div class="row">   
           <section class="col col-5 col-md-offset-1">
               <div id="inline-start" name="pocetni"></div>
                  </section>
           <section class="col col-5">
               <div id="inline-finish" name="zavrsni"></div>
                  </section>
 </div>
```

and I've tried to get it with:

```
<?php
/* some previous code that gets other elements and works */
$startDate = $_POST['pocetni'];
$endDate = $_POST['zavrsni'];

/*some print code for other elements*/
print("<strong>Datum dolaska:</strong> $startDate<br/>");
print("<strong>Datum odlaska:</strong> $endDate<br/>");

?>
```

Thank you !

Comment: you need to have an actual form with a method POST with form inputs and then submitting the form.

Comment: Yes, I have it, this is a <section> inside a <form>. The other inputs work fine, except this one.